# mysqli php sql statement does not execute

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have the strangest problem and I can figure out what is happening. There are no error being displayed and I've `var_dump`ed `$stmt` and for will just not return anything.

The test data that i am trying to retrieve is correct and when i try the statement manually through phpmyadmin it would perfectly so I'm stumped any ideas?

```
$sql = "SELECT UserID,Password FROM Account WHERE ProfileName = ? OR  Email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$username = strtolower($username);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $username);
$stmt->bind_result($userID, $dbPassword);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: are you sure to bind `$username` twice?

Comment: Ever heard of error handling?

Comment: well i have tried rename the variable so they were different but nothing happened

Comment: the whole thing is in a try catch but nothing gets caught

Comment: `echo $sql;` ..then execute the same via `phpmyadmin` and check if something really pouring in or not

Comment: Do you use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` (or a variant of that) to ensure that exceptions are thrown?

Comment: not sure how you use mysql_report with OOP

Comment: See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php (although `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` should work).

Comment: No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT UserID,Password FROM Account WHERE ProfileName = ? OR  Email = ? LIMIT 1 is the error i got no idea what it means though

Answer (score 2):

The `bind_result()` call must be done after `execute()` not before.

Change to:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($userID, $dbPassword);
$stmt->fetch();
```

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch().

Also, you can narrow down the problem by checking if `prepare()` succeeded and then subsequently if there are any rows:

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userID, $dbPassword);

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
    else
    {
         echo 'Query succeeded, but no rows found!';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
    // use trigger_error() not echo in production, after development
}
```

If `prepare()` fails, it means there is a either a connection error, syntax error or missing table/field name in the query.

Comment: prepare statement returns true so that dosent seem to be the problem

Comment: Does it say no rows found?

Comment: turned up exactly as expected, ran the query through phpmyadmin again with the var_dump value and it found the row so i'm not sure why it's just this query. All my other queries run fine

Comment: Did you do the var_dump right before the bind_param so that you can rule out any other code modifying the username? Also verify you are connected to the correct database (has happened before!)

Comment: $username is fine when i checked the var_dump and the connection runs off a connection class which is used all over the site and works for other statements. It's annoying cause it's not a complicated query yet it's proving to be one of the most difficult to diagnose